# Ошибка java: cannot find symbol | Spring

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea, flyway

Есть проект Spring, базовые функции Интернет-магазина. Работал над проектом, все было хорошо, все запускалось, но в один прекрасный момент, на очередной RUN проекта, появилась вот такая проблема[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не могу понять, что именно произошло и почему он не видит переменную UserDTO, а также методы в классе. С последнего запуска программы я не трогал этот класс. Также как и не трогал класс объекта UserDTO.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пытался найти ответ на свой вопрос, но везде пишут, что мол нет объявления объекта или реализации методов. Но вот дело в том, что они есть

Перезапускал проект, может как-то lombok слетел, хотя если навести на методы в IDE то можно увидеть следующее:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Искал разные решения на просторах интернета, но ничего не подошло под меня, обработка аннотаций включена. Плагины по работе с lombok установлены

Comment: Переписал аннотации в классе UserDTO и User, в итоге все заработало, но как такое возможно, что как-то выборочно аннотации поломались... в других классах, сущностях - > все работает также на аннотациях

Comment: Всякая фигня бывает с идеей, препроцессор почему-то сломался, иногда помогает рестарт

Comment: Насколько я понял - проблема в конфронтации Lombok и MapConstruct